# Problema añadir fecha, formato

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, angularjs, bootstrap

Hola chicos mi problema es que intento meter con un datepicker formateado con fecha yyyy-mm-dd, la aplicacion la estoy realizando en angular entonces a la hora de dar el añadir mi cita no me añade nada y es porque pasa algo con el formato. Si comento el div y pongo la fecha a mano me lo pilla perfectamente, a ver si me podeis ayudar. El codigo es este:

```
  <div class="input-group date fecha">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaInicio" ng-model="cita.fechaInicio"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.fecha').datepicker({
        format:"yyyy-mm-dd",
        language:"es"
      });
      </script>
```

y la consulta despues del submit es esta:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO citas (fechaInicio, hora, descripcion, id, horaCompleta)
VALUES ('$data->fechaInicio', '$data->hora', '$data->descripcion', $id ,1)";
$qry = $conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();
?>
```

EDITO despues de la solucion de @friki..

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaInicio" ng-model="cita.fechaInicio">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#fechaInicio").datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
});
</script>
```

Sigue mostrando bien todo, pero no añade la cita.

añado img de consola:

[image: iamgen 1]
[image: iamgen2]

ACTUALIZO:
He estado probando cosas, y es curioso si elijo la fecha con el datepicker dando click no me lo pilla, pero si de la fecha que me genera por ejemplo cambio o borro un numero y lo pongo a mano si me hace la inserción bien...

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás mandando tus datos y cómo se ve la variable `$data` en php?

Comment: Puedes añadir dos comprobaciones de datos? 1) En el PHP añadir un `echo($sql)` para ver cual es el INSERT que se intenta realizar. 2) Añadir una etiqueta donde se vea en formato `JSON` el objeto `cita`: `<pre>{{cita | json}}</pre>`, posteanos los resultados para ver donde puede andar el problema por favor

Comment: peta el programa no me deja darle al botón de guardar, y ya ni me saca a ver las citas como antes. añadi el echo en insertar.php y el pre en listar. añado captura del mensaje de la consola que me sale.

Comment: En la captura que nos pones veo las cabeceras de petición y respuesta pero no veo ninguna de las cosas que te indiqué. Como la `$sql` que se genera en el php ni el contenido del objeto `cita`. Podrías actualizar la pregunta con esa información?

Answer (score 2):

El problema principal que estoy viendo es que el `input` donde se debería de estar guardando el valor de la fecha seleccionada del componente `datepicker` de `jQuery UI` no está bien enlazado.

Estás enlazando al componente `datepicker` el `div` con la clase `fecha` en lugar de asociar el `input`.

Te preopongo 3 soluciones:

### Usar el selector del input al que quieres aplicar el datepicker

```
<div class="input-group date fecha">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaInicio" ng-model="cita.fechaInicio"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#fechaInicio').datepicker({
        format:"yyyy-mm-dd",
        language:"es"
      });
</script>
```

### Usar un selector para el input hijo de la clase .fecha

```
<div class="input-group date fecha">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaInicio" ng-model="cita.fechaInicio"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('.fecha input').datepicker({
        format:"yyyy-mm-dd",
        language:"es"
      });
</script>
```

### Usar la propiedad altField del componente datepicker

```
<div class="input-group date fecha">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaInicio" ng-model="cita.fechaInicio"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('.fecha').datepicker({
        altField: '#fechaInicio'
        format:"yyyy-mm-dd",
        language:"es"
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Que tal compi, he mirado tus soluciones y lo he dejado asi = pero sigue sin añadirme la cita, simplemente va a la pantalla donde me muestra todas las citas pero no añade la nueva.
Te dejo el cambio modificado arriba en el post @frikinside

Comment: he actualizado el post @frikinside